# Handle the response from Apex in Lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

I am trying to check on the response from the Apex Class and change the toast depending on it. My Lightning component is like below

```
passCaseToCS_helper : function(c,e,h) {
    var set_action1 = c.get("c.passCase");
    set_action1.setParams({caseId: c.get('v.recordId')});
    set_action1.setCallback(this, function(result)
    {
        var resultApex =  result.getReturnValue();
        if (result.getState() == 'SUCCESS' && resultApex.contains('Assign'))
            {
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                message: resultApex,
                type: "error",
                mode: 'sticky'
                });
                toastEvent.fire(); 
            }        
            else if(result.getState() == 'SUCCESS' && resultApex.contains('Sucessfully'))
            {
                var toastEvent = $A.get("e.force:showToast");
                toastEvent.setParams({
                    message: resultApex ,
                    type: 'success',
                    mode: 'pester'
                });
                toastEvent.fire(); 
            }                
            else if(result.getState() != 'SUCCESS')
            {
                $A.get("e.force:showToast")
                .setParams({
                    type: 'error',
                    mode: 'pester',
                    message: 'Case Cant be Updated!'}).fire();
    }
    $A.get("e.force:refreshView").fire();
});
$A.enqueueAction(set_action1);       
}
```

[image]

I even tried changing the code like `if (result.getState() == 'SUCCESS' && result.getReturnValue().contains('Assign'))`

Even that throws error

[image]

I am not sure what I am missing here. How can I check the response string and fire toast depending on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript, you can use the method String.prototype.includes, or String.prototype.match (or several others). String.contains is an Apex method (and Java, and other languages), but JavaScript does not have such a method. Alternatively, you can use a RegExp.

## includes

```
if(result.getState() === 'SUCCESS' && resultApex.includes('Successfully')) {
```

## match

```
if(result.getState() === 'SUCCESS' && resultApex.match(/Successfully/)) {
```

## RegExp

```
if(result.getState() === 'SUCCESS' && /Successfully/.test(resultApex)) {
```